# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches - where is my mistake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my test for the chapters controller

```
require 'test_helper'

class ChaptersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    test "should get index_nklm" do
        get :index_nklm
        assert_response :success
    end

    test "should get show_nklm" do
        get show_chapter_nklm_path(chapters(:one))
        assert_response :success
    end
end
```

This is my routes.rb

```
 get 'chapters_nklm' => 'chapters#index_nklm', as: :chapters_nklm
 get 'chapter_nklm/:id/show' => 'chapters#show_nklm', as: :show_chapter_nklm
```

This is my chapters.yml fixture:

```
one:
  id: 12
  chapter_name: MyString
  chapter: MyString
  description: MyText
  display: 1
  subject_id: 1
```

This is (part of) the chapters_controller.rb:

```
def show_nklm
  @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
end
```

And I don't know why I get this error message?

```
Error:
ChaptersControllerTest#test_should_get_show_nklm:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/chapter_nklm/12/show", :controller=>"chapters"}
    test/controllers/chapters_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ChaptersControllerTest>'
```

But when I copy "/chapter_nklm/12/show" into the browser, everything works fine? Where is my mistake and which concept didn't I understand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is waiting to receive an action as a symbol object, you're passing the whole route alias, plus the object needed.

Try using the `params` option with your route:

```
test 'should get show_nklm' do
  get :show_nklm, params: { id: chapters(:one).id }
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: `show_chapter_nklm_path(@chapter)` would still break in the application, no?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider doing something like:

```
resources :chapters do 
  get :nklm, to: :show_nklm
end
```

Which would give you:

```
  chapter_nklm GET    /chapters/:chapter_id/nklm(.:format)       chapters#show_nklm
      chapters GET    /chapters(.:format)                        chapters#index
               POST   /chapters(.:format)                        chapters#create
   new_chapter GET    /chapters/new(.:format)                    chapters#new
  edit_chapter GET    /chapters/:id/edit(.:format)               chapters#edit
       chapter GET    /chapters/:id(.:format)                    chapters#show
               PATCH  /chapters/:id(.:format)                    chapters#update
               PUT    /chapters/:id(.:format)                    chapters#update
               DELETE /chapters/:id(.:format)                    chapters#destroy
```

This strikes me as a bit more *conventional*, and should allow you to do:

```
class ChaptersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  ...

  test "should get show_nklm" do
    get chapter_nklm_path(chapters(:one))
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too! But it's a little bit complicated to explain why I did it my way. One is also probably that I'm new to rails and poke around. For my next project I'll remember your style.